# C# Hangman Game Error

Tags: c#

I keep having this error.

*ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled.
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index*

Below is the complete code of the form that has the problem and it is where the Hangman game takes place.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Hangman_APPD_Assignment
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The List labels = new List(); is the label that the makeLabels() method is going to use it.

```
    String w = "";
    List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
    int score = 0, missed = 0, correctCount = 0, gameCount = 1;
```

The code below is when the user clicks the QUIT button, the application will close.

```
    private void btnQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

The code below is when the form loads or shows up, the makeLabels() method is used.

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        makeLabels();
    }
```

The code below is to use the random word and convert in to a string replacing each alphabet with a symbol '_'. The converted string will be put inside a label called Labels.

```
    private void makeLabels()
    {
        w = getRandomWord().ToLower();
        w.Replace(" ", "");

        char[] letters = w.ToCharArray();
        int space = 569 / letters.Length - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
        {
            labels.Add(new Label());
            labels[i].Location = new Point((i * space) + 10, 109);
            labels[i].Parent = groupBox2;
            labels[i].Text = "_" + i;
            labels[i].BringToFront();
            labels[i].CreateControl();
        }


        lblLength.Text = letters.Length.ToString();
    }
```

The code below is a method to create a new game when 1) the user guesses the word completely or 2) the user runs out of guesses.

```
    private void newGame()
    {
        gameCount++;

        if (gameCount == 15)
        {
            this.Hide();
            if (score >= 7)
            {
                Form4 f4 = new Form4();
                f4.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                Form6 f6 = new Form6();
                f6.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            getRandomWord();
            makeLabels();
            enableLetterButtons();
            lblMissed.Text = "";
            hangPic.Image = Hangman_APPD_Assignment.Properties.Resources.part0;
        }
    }
```

The code below gets a random word from the string array to be used as the mystery word in the game.

```
    public string getRandomWord()
    {
        Random randomNum = new Random();

        String[] words = {"virus", "network", "syntax", "router", "switch", "worms", "trojan", "email", "bios",
                             "cmos", "ram", "cipher", "malware", "botnet", "cookies", "patches", "cryptograph",
                             "metamorphic", "polymorphic", "rootkit", "logicbomb", "spam", "spyware", "keyloggers",
                             "adware", "software", "hardware", "botherder", "phishing", "whaling", "pharming", 
                             "vishing", "spim", "topology", "tailgating", "loop", "java", "motherboard", "unique",
                             "parameter"};
        int randomNumber = randomNum.Next(0, (words.Length - 1));

        return words[randomNumber];
    }
```

The code below is to change the picture every time the user guesses wrongly.

```
    private void setPicture(int wrongTry)
    {
        switch(wrongTry)
        {
            case 0: 
                hangPic.Image = Hangman_APPD_Assignment.Properties.Resources.part0;
                break;
            case 1: 
                hangPic.Image = Hangman_APPD_Assignment.Properties.Resources.part1;
                break;
            case 2:
                hangPic.Image = Hangman_APPD_Assignment.Properties.Resources.part2;
                break;
            case 3:
                hangPic.Image = Hangman_APPD_Assignment.Properties.Resources.part3;
                break;
            case 4:
                hangPic.Image = Hangman_APPD_Assignment.Properties.Resources.part4;
                break;
            case 5:
                hangPic.Image = Hangman_APPD_Assignment.Properties.Resources.part5;
                break;
            case 6:
                hangPic.Image = Hangman_APPD_Assignment.Properties.Resources.part6;
                break;
        }
    }
```

The code below is to call a method when the user clicks one of the alphabet buttons.

```
    private void checkGuessedLetter(string wordToGuess, string guessedLetter, Button buttonName)
    {
        int strLength = wordToGuess.Length;

        char letter = guessedLetter.ToCharArray()[0];
        buttonName.Enabled = false;

        if (w.Contains(guessedLetter))
        {
            char[] LS = w.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < LS.Length; i++)
            {
                if (LS[i] == letter)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The value of w is " + w + " AND " + i);
                    labels[i].Text = letter.ToString();
                    conditionPic.Image = Hangman_APPD_Assignment.Properties.Resources.correctpic;
                    correctCount++;
                    MessageBox.Show("You got correct " + correctCount + " time(s).");
                    if (correctCount == strLength)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Good job! Keep it up, matey!", "Victory!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
                        score++;
                        lblScore.Text = score.ToString();
                        newGame();
                        missed = 0;
                        correctCount = 0;
                        labels.Clear();
                    }
                }

                foreach (Label l in labels)
                    if (l.Text == "__") return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            conditionPic.Image = Hangman_APPD_Assignment.Properties.Resources.wrong;
            lblMissed.Text += " " + letter.ToString() + " |";
            missed++;
            MessageBox.Show("You missed " + missed + " time(s).");
            setPicture(missed);

            if (missed == 6)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unfortunately, you lost this round... Make sure you won't let this happen again, "
                + "or else you will end up in Davy Jones' Locker.", "Defeat!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                newGame();
                missed = 0;
                correctCount = 0;
                labels.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

The code below is to get the score that is accumulated at the lblScore label to be shown in the next form.

```
    public int getScore()
    {
        int score = int.Parse(lblScore.Text);
        return score;
    }
```

The codes below is to call a method when the user clicks a button that contains an alphabet to guess the word in the Hangman game.

```
    private void Abtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "a", Abtn);
    }

    private void Bbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "b", Bbtn);
    }

    private void Cbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "c", Cbtn);
    }

    private void Dbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "d", Dbtn);
    }

    private void Ebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "e", Ebtn);
    }

    private void Fbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "f", Fbtn);
    }

    private void Gbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "g", Gbtn);
    }

    private void Hbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "h", Hbtn);
    }

    private void Ibtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "i", Ibtn);
    }

    private void Jbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "j", Jbtn);
    }

    private void Kbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "k", Kbtn);
    }

    private void Lbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "l", Lbtn);
    }

    private void Mbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "m", Mbtn);
    }

    private void Nbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "n", Nbtn);
    }

    private void Obtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "o", Obtn);
    }

    private void Pbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "p", Pbtn);
    }

    private void Qbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "q", Qbtn);
    }

    private void Rbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "r", Rbtn);
    }

    private void Sbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "s", Sbtn);
    }

    private void Tbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "t", Tbtn);
    }

    private void Ubtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "u", Ubtn);
    }

    private void Vbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "v", Vbtn);
    }

    private void Wbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "w", Wbtn);
    }

    private void Xbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "x", Xbtn);
    }

    private void Ybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "y", Ybtn);
    }

    private void Zbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkGuessedLetter(w, "z", Zbtn);
    }
```

The code below is to enable back all the buttons that has been clicked on the previous game.

```
    private void enableLetterButtons()
    {
        Abtn.Enabled = true;
        Bbtn.Enabled = true;
        Cbtn.Enabled = true;
        Dbtn.Enabled = true;
        Ebtn.Enabled = true;
        Fbtn.Enabled = true;
        Gbtn.Enabled = true;
        Hbtn.Enabled = true;
        Ibtn.Enabled = true;
        Jbtn.Enabled = true;
        Kbtn.Enabled = true;
        Lbtn.Enabled = true;
        Mbtn.Enabled = true;
        Nbtn.Enabled = true;
        Obtn.Enabled = true;
        Pbtn.Enabled = true;
        Qbtn.Enabled = true;
        Rbtn.Enabled = true;
        Sbtn.Enabled = true;
        Tbtn.Enabled = true;
        Ubtn.Enabled = true;
        Vbtn.Enabled = true;
        Wbtn.Enabled = true;
        Xbtn.Enabled = true;
        Ybtn.Enabled = true;
        Zbtn.Enabled = true;
    }
```

The code below is to close the application when the user clicked the X button on the top right-hand corner of the application.

```
    private void btnOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

}

P.S. I'm sorry I forgot to put in where the error comes from.
So the error is at the

```
labels[i].Text = letter.ToString();
```

in the checkGuessedLetter(string wordToGuess, string guessedLetter, Button buttonName) method.

Comment: The Exception has something called a Stack Trace, which tells you exactly at which line the error occurred. Also, you should learn about debugging your code: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vDKXIq_9A (I didn't see all of the video)

Comment: if you commented your code, you wouldn't need to keep adding "The code below..."  It would be one long block of code.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at the error line and see how many objects labels contains?  It appears that your labels aren't being created correctly.

Comment: labels contains 6 objects? which is the same as the length of the word as in the number of alphabets that the word has

Comment: ..and value of `LS.Length` = ? and value of `i` when you get that error = ?

Comment: @har07 The value of LS.Length is the number of alphabets in the word that is generated from getRandomWord() method. The value of i was the index number of the alphabet in the word that I guessed correctly. Like the letter 'a' in apple, I guessed 'a' and the value of i was 0.

Comment: That is what you expect but not always what actually happen. As others suggested, try to debug your program to see the actual condition, how many object actually in `Labels`, what is value of `i`..

Comment: @har07 The number of object in labels is the length of the char array letters in the makeLabels() method. And the value of i is the index number of the alphabet in the word that I guessed correctly. For example, the letter 'o' is in the word "worms", I guessed the letter 'o' and the value of i was 1.

Comment: Ok i got it. But I'm asking for those values, particularly when the error happened..

Comment: @user2622438: I think the point har07 was making is that you seem to be saying what you think those values *should* be. We know they aren't what you think they are since we are getting an exception so we need to make sure we are in debug mode to see the actual values. The error means that the value of `i` was too high for the number of items in `labels` so you need to look at what the value of `i` is (given by your message box just before the exception) and the number of items in `labels`. If `labels` has the wrong number of items then you need to investigate why that is.

Comment: Also it might be interesting to see what the word is and the letter chosen. Does it only happen for letters near the end of words or would it even throw that error for the first letter of a word, etc.

Comment: Just now, I tried debugging it again and using the breakpoint, the word that I had to guess is "router". So I guessed the letter 'u', and then the application paused and I looked up at the values, labels had 6 items in it and the value of i was 2. And I really looked at the Locals tab...

Comment: @Chris Err... The first round was going well but when I get a new word which is the second round, when I guessed a correct alphabet, the error occurs...

Comment: For debugging hopefully it breaks when it throws the exception and you can look at the values there. If not you should check the values every time so you can see what they are before it breaks. Given the answer I've put below you should have noticed that `labels` was empty when it actually threw the exception.

Comment: And I should note since it can sometimes be unclear on the internet that I am not chastising you for not doing these things. I'm telling you where you went wrong so you know better for next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in these lines:

```
newGame();
missed = 0;
correctCount = 0;
labels.Clear();
```

The key thing is to stop and think about what `newGame` does and then think about what you do afterwards? Since this is homework (I assume from some of the names) really go and think about it.

Done? Good. So hopefully you realised that your `newGame` method calls `MakeLabels` to generate the labels and that you then a couple of lines later clear out `labels`. This means that for subsequent games your `labels` list will always be empty.

The correct fix for this is that the last three lines I quoted are all part of creating a new game so should be in that method. And indeed you only need to clear the `labels` when you make new ones so make that part of that method too. Do this and your program will be clearer and hopefully work too! :)

Comment: Thank you! Yay! You are a lifesaver. Thank you so much! :) Good job! So happy right now.

Comment: I hope you are happy because you learnt something about debugging and good code structure and not just because you got the answer. ;-)